# Use Embedded Ruby to conditionally include a hidden form field in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to use Embedded Ruby to include a hidden field in a form if a url parameter was included in the request that rendered the form.  For some reason, the hidden fields are not included regardless of the existence of url parameters.  It is part of a Rails 3.2 application.  Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the form in question that is part of my index.html.erb view:

```
<form action="/contacts" method="get" id="contacts-index">
  <input name="city" value="<%= params[:city] %>" type="hidden">
  <input name="state" value="<%= params[:state] %>" type="hidden">
  <input name="zip" value="<%= params[:zip] %>" type="hidden">
  <% if params[:fi_ase] == true or params[:fi_ase] == false %>
    <input name="fi_ase" value="<%= params[:fi_ase] %>" type="hidden">
  <% end %>
  <% if params[:fi_ame] == true or params[:fi_ame] == false %>
    <input name="fi_ame" value="<%= params[:fi_ame] %>" type="hidden">
  <% end %>
.
.
.
.
</form>
```

The page renders just fine but the "fi_ase" and "fi_ame" hidden fields are not there after sending a request to /contacts?fi_ase=true&fi_ame=true

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<% if params[:fi_ase] == "true" or params[:fi_ase] == "false" %>
  <input name="fi_ase" value="<%= params[:fi_ase] %>" type="hidden">
<% end %>
<% if params[:fi_ame] == "true" or params[:fi_ame] == "false" %>
  <input name="fi_ame" value="<%= params[:fi_ame] %>" type="hidden">
<% end %>
```

[parameter values are always strings;](http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6371-action-controller-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag('fi_ase', params[:fi_ase]) if params[:fi_ase] == "true" or params[:fi_ase] == "false" %> 
<%= hidden_field_tag('fi_ame', params[:fi_ame]) if params[:fi_ame] == "true" or params[:fi_ame] == "false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Try this,

<%= hidden_field_tag "some_id", @some %>  tag will help you..